# How to implement retry and recover logic with Spring Reactive Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, project-reactor, reactive-kafka

We are using the https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka project for implementing Spring Reactive Kafka. But we want to utilize Kafka retry and recover logic with reactive Kafka.
Can anyone provide some sample code?

Comment: You can check this way, I am using reactor's retry method to do the retry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400971/how-to-retry-failed-consumerrecord-in-reactor-kafka

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using spring ecosystem for retry and recovery you can use spring-retry looks at there documentation [spring -retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html). There are enough references available on web.

A sample example below class is consuming messages from kafka topic and processing.

> The method consuming is marked Retryable, so in case there is
> exception processing it will retry and if retry doesn't succeed then
> the corresponding recovery method will be called.

```
public class KafkaListener{
  
 
  @KafkaListener(topic="books-topic", id ="group-1")
  @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, value = Exception.class))
  public void consuming(String message){
   //  To do message processing 
   //  Whenever there is exception thrown from this method
   //   - it will retry 3 times in total
   //   - Even after retry we get exception then it will be handed of to below 
   //     recover method recoverConsuming 
  
   }

   @Recover
   public void recoverConsuming(Exception exception, String message){
     // Recovery logic 
     // you can implement your recovery scenario
    }
  
 }
```

Comment: @KafkaListener is not reactive.

Comment: yes kafkalistener is not reactive. [spring-reactive/vertx.io is reactive framework]
My point is u can use spring retry